# Is this a copy? but why it works like a reference?

Tags: c++

The below code, `Value r = foo(i)`, is `r` a reference or a copy?

```
Value foo(int i) {
  return Value::New(i);
}

Value bar(Arg x) {
  // should I use Value& r = foo(x.getIndex());
  Value r = foo(x.getIndex());
  x.close();
  return r;
}
```

---

I tested

```
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

class Value {
public:
    Value() {
        printf("construct\n");
    }
};

Value foo(){
    Value a;
    return a;
}

Value bar() {
    Value b = foo();
    return b;
}

int main(){
    Value c = bar();
}
```

only construct 1 times.

Answer (score 2):

Depends. If `Value` is `typedef`'d to some reference type (e.g. `int&`) then yes, `foo` would be a reference. Otherwise no. As Paolo points out, however, `Value` has a member function `New` and thus cannot be a reference type. Therefore you are passing/returning `Value`s by copy, not by reference.

---

Post Edit: The reason you don't see your string message printed several times is simple: It's only printed when the default ctor is invoked. Implement an actual copy-ctor and you will see a lot more messages, each time a `Value` is copied.

Comment: `Value` cannot be `typedef`'d to a reference type, because it's being used as a class inside `foo`.

Comment: @PaoloCapriotti: I answered before the question was edited and thereby changed substantially.

Comment: No, I was referring to the expression `Value::New(i)`, which was already there. If `Value` were a reference type, that expression wouldn't compile.

Comment: @PaoloCapriotti: Sorry, you are right. I must have missed that `::New`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Copy. You would notice reference by the `&` sign.

The real question is what `foo` returns. If it returns a reference  - it makes sense to use a reference, otherwise if it returns a copy (i.e.: the return type is `Value`, not `Value&`), you'll just be referencing a copy, so what's the point (and you would probably get a compiler warning or error)?

Comment: `Value* foo(int i) { return &Value::New(i); }` is this better.

Comment: @guilin桂林 - what does this have to do with your question? You're returning a pointer here, it's neither a value nor reference (with regards to the Value data type).

Answer (score 0):

It's a copy. Also, you can't use a reference there (as in the commented line), because the return value of `foo` is stored in a temporary and gets destructed at the end of the line, creating a dangling reference.

Answer (score 0):

Copy, because `foo(int)` does not return a reference.

Comment: `Value& foo(int)`. It's a Bad idea, because you're returning a dangling reference. Leaving it as value lets the compiler use (N)RVO and transform `Value r = foo.getIndex(i)` to `Value r = Value::New(i)`.

Comment: I am confused now, you mean that the compiler does not construct twice?

Comment: Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization , because the answer is both yes and no.

Answer (score 0):

It is a copy for two reasons. The first one,as pointed by others, is that foo returns a copy of `Value`, i.e. it does not return `Value &`.

The second reason is that this (misleading) syntax

```
Value r = foo(x.getIndex());
```

Does not have anything to do with the assignment operator, it is actually equivalent to:

```
Value r( foo( x.getIndex() ) );
```

The new object of class Value is built with another instance of class Value, so the copy constructor is invoked.

About the question in your source code:

```
Value bar(Arg x) {
  // should I use Value& r = foo(x.getIndex());
  Value r = foo(x.getIndex());
  x.close();
  return r;
}
```

No, you shouldn't use `Value&`, since in order to keep it effective you should change the return value of bar to `Value&`, and you cannot return a reference to an object that will be end its life when the `bar()` function ends.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit for the updated question:

> only construct 1 times

Because the standard explicitly allows the compiler to optimize away copy construction (even if it has side affects). Your code is easily optimized by the compiler using `RVO` and `NRVO`. This basically allows the compiler to construct the object once at the destination (thus you see no copies).

#### Original Answer

Its a copy

The function foo() returns a value of type `Value`

```
Value foo(int i)
```

If you want to return a reference to an object of type value you need to indicate this in the function signature:

```
Value & fooRef(int i)
//   ^^^ Notice the & symbol
```

Also the variable 'r' is an object. So even if you assign a reference to it. It will then make a copy of the original object returned.

```
Value  rv = fooRef(1); // fooRef() returns a reference to an object.
                       // But here we make a copy into rv

Value& rf = fooRef(1); // fooRef() returns a reference.
                       // rf is a reference and keeps a reference to the object returned by
                       // fooRef()
```

Comment: I update my question, why it does not construct again if it is a copy?

Comment: @guilin桂林: Because if the compiler wants to remove an unnecessary copy it is allowed too. So in most situations it will.